# Regex to find multiple file names in text string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find file names in a string, I cannot predict if the names will have any delimiter around them, the names can be arbitrary length and contain spaces but they will start with a number and end with a file type.

For example in the string 'workplan to meet 2 March deadline.doc (0399 F_1221A.pdf)'
I want to match 2 March deadline.doc and 0399 F_1221A.pdf

The regex I am using `/\d{1,4} .*(\.docx|\.doc|\.ppt|xls|\.pdf)/gi`
is returning a single match '2 March deadline.doc (0399 F_1221A.pdf'

See https://regex101.com/r/yUkABU/3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MymsMan, can you please attach some more samples and what you mean by *is returning a single match* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lazy quantifier instead of a greedy one: `.*?` instead of `.*`.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy

Comment: *converting the useful part of my answer to a comment on your answer if you don't mind my doing so.*  Here's a demo using a fork of OPs regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/cCwAyl/1

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks for the example :)

Comment: Posting a link is hardly useful. Real examples would be.

Answer (score 1):

Try Matching everything except for a period

```
\d{1,4} [^\.]*(\.docx|\.doc|\.ppt|xls|\.pdf)
//        ^^ this part
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/rWxWND/1)

Comment: That works for the example shown but I suspect other file names may contain embedded dots so I will use the other solution